# Error on Chart.js with Electron - Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts, electron, chart.js

First off, I have checked the following posts:

- [Chart.js unable to create chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153324/chart-js-unable-to-create-chart)
- [Error on Chartjs and Angular 5 - "can't acquire context from the given item"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330221/error-on-chartjs-and-angular-5-cant-acquire-context-from-the-given-item)
- [chart.js Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280857/chart-js-failed-to-create-chart-cant-acquire-context-from-the-given-item)
- [Angular/Chart.js error: Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046386/angular-chart-js-error-failed-to-create-chart-cant-acquire-context-from-the-g?rq=1)

None seem to be describing the same problem I have, which is why I've resorted to creating a new post.

I've isolated the code down to a minimum - which is really just the electron boilerplate + chart.js boilerplate. I've posted it in the following git repo https://github.com/HerveSV/chartjsElectronTest.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your Electron application.</p>

    <div>
      <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
   
    <script defer src="render.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**preload.js** (accesses node api in place of render.js, for safety)

```
const { contextBridge } = require('electron')
const Chart = require("chart.js");


contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electron',
    {
        createChart: (ctx, params) => {
          let chart = new Chart(ctx, params);
        }
    }
)
```

**render.js**

```
// neither work
let ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
//let ctx = document.getElementById("chart");

console.log(ctx);
window.electron.createChart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

There isn't much I can say about the problem, the electron app runs, everything else is functional, but where the chart should be there's a blank space and the following error message is shown: Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item. The electron boilerplate works just fine for everything else, so I don't believe that's the point of error. I copied the chart.js boilerplate code directly from https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/, so that should be working too. I made sure to acquire the 2d context of the canvas element. I'm wondering if this is a bug with the chart.js node module - but if that were the case, where are all the error reports?

If anyone could provide some more insight, that'd be greatly appreciated. I'm simply quite lost and out of options here.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but maybe this will help other people with the same problem.
I had the same problem and i got it working by moving the

ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");

inside the preload.js
it seems that you cant pass a domobject from renderer.js to preload.js

Comment: Thanks dear. i got solution from this